# Count number of row in column B starting from cell B15

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and would like to count the number row that contain data starting from cell B15 with B1 to B14 will not be counted. Anyway to modify the code to achieve it?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lastRow As Long

   With ActiveSheet
   Range("B15").Select
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   MsgBox lastRow
   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) equivalent of `COUNTA`, ie

```
MsgBox Application.CountA(Range("b15:b" & Rows.Count))
```

*(Also caters for any blanks cells in that range)*

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim numRow As Long

    If IsEmpty(Cells(15, 2)) Then
        numRow = 0
    Else
        numRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 14
    End If

    MsgBox numRow
End Sub
```

Comment: A little more detail: 1) This only counts the number of cells from the last to 15 (you should actually subtract 14 instead), not the number of cells "that contain data" (see question). 2) If an answer you post works only under certain assumptions not specified by the OP, it is most convenient that you state it clearly in the answer, so you don't leave it for the readers to guess it.

Comment: @sancho.s don't be mad just because I add a comment in your previous answer. Sorry man about that man. I just want to help.

Comment: I am not mad, at all, there is no need to appease. I only meant to help you round up a better answer, and thus have a better SO for all of us. That is all that matters, for me. But it appears that I missed the target, as you did not even care about fixing the 15 for a 14 (not even mentioning in the answer that it requires a special condition, and even in that case that it does not answer the question of the OP).

Comment: Just for you @sancho.s. Thanks for you review.

Comment: Did you try your Sub under different conditions, to check that it does what it is supposed to do? Good luck.